# Connecting to Samba from AWS AD Connector

Tags: samba, active-directory, amazon-web-services

I have set up a Samba 4 Active Directory domain controller in AWS EC2 for my small business. I am trying to configure AWS Workmail to use this directory. I have followed Amazon's instructions [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/directoryservice/latest/admin-guide/directory_ad_connector.html) to set up an AD Connector instance linked to my Samba 4 installation. The AWS Directory Service console shows the connector's status as "Active," and I was able to set up a Workmail organization using that directory. However, when any of the management dashboards for that organization, an error banner is displayed that reads:

```
The connection to your directory cannot be established, error message
reported by Directory:
Authentication failed. Request id: 22b5a534-e08c-4e1a-9b5e-396f8922ebe8.
You can verify that your settings are correct using AWS Directory Service 
Documentation. Contact AWS Support if the issue remains.
```

In the Samba server's logs, I find the following:

```
ldb_wrap open of secrets.ldb
Kerberos: TGS-REQ awsadconnector@CORP.MYBUSINESS.COM from 
ipv4:172.30.5.246:56436 for ldap/addc01.corp.mybusiness.com@CORP.MYBUSINESS.COM
Kerberos: TGS-REQ authtime: 2019-10-20T23:06:00 starttime: 2019-10-20T23:06:00 endtime: 2019-10-21T09:06:00 renew till: unset
Terminating connection - 'kdc_tcp_call_loop: tstream_read_pdu_blob_recv() - NT_STATUS_CONNECTION_DISCONNECTED'
single_terminate: reason[kdc_tcp_call_loop: tstream_read_pdu_blob_recv() - NT_STATUS_CONNECTION_DISCONNECTED]
Starting GENSEC mechanism gssapi_krb5_sasl
gensec_gssapi: NO credentials were delegated
SASL/GSSAPI Connection from client will have no cryptographic protection
Terminating connection - 'ldapsrv_call_loop: tstream_read_pdu_blob_recv() - NT_STATUS_CONNECTION_DISCONNECTED'
single_terminate: reason[ldapsrv_call_loop: tstream_read_pdu_blob_recv() - NT_STATUS_CONNECTION_DISCONNECTED]
dreplsrv_notify_schedule(5) scheduled for: Sun Oct 20 23:06:09 2019 UTC
dreplsrv_notify_schedule(5) scheduled for: Sun Oct 20 23:06:14 2019 UTC
```

Can anyone tell me what is causing this problem, and suggest a solution? Has anyone succeeded in getting AWS AD Connector to interoperate with Samba 4?

Comment: I was able to get past the above problem by adding this line to smb.conf:

    ldap server require strong auth = no

I am now getting a new error on the AWS WorkMail dashboard for the organization:

  undefined: Unable to execute HTTP request: Read timed out (Service: null; Status Code: 0; Error Code: null; Request ID: null)

This generated 548 lines of log messages, which I am now going through to figure out what is relevant. At the moment, I am focusing on this line:

    ldapsrv_do_call: Critical extension 2.16.840.1.113730.3.4.9 is not known to this server

Comment: This OID refers to the "Virtual List View" extension, which apparently was added to Samba in version 4.5. I am now running version 4.3.11, so the next task is to migrate to a newer Samba version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The authentication error issue was fixed by adding

```
 ldap server require strong auth = no
```

to `/etc/smb.conf`. This fix, however, revealed another problem. The version of Samba that I was running did not support Virtual List Views. That issue caused the following message to appear in logs:

```
 ldapsrv_do_call: Critical extension 2.16.840.1.113730.3.4.9 is not known to this server
```

To address this, I installed a more recent version of Samba (4.6.7). This version, it turned out, required one more change: this version of Samba appeared to be using a wider range of values for RPC endpoints. I opened ports 1024-65535 for TCP traffic in the Amazon security group.

With all of these changes, I am now able to see my Samba users in Amazon WorkMail